# JPA criteria API: How to use IN keyword and query the result for another predicate?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Sorry for the bad title, I don't really know how to word it better:

I have the following tablestructure:

```
Table A --> Table B  <-- Table C (proceeds) --> Table D(prcoeeding_status)
--------    --------     -------                -------
 aID         bID           cID                   dID
 ...         ....          created             textValue
 f_bID       ....          f_bID       
                           f_dID
```

meaning A and C have a foreign key pointing to B and C also has a foreign key pointing to D

I have a predicate like this (root being the Table A):

```
constraintCondition = (TableA.join("Table B key")
                        .joinList("Table C Key")
                        .join("Table D Key").get("value from table D"))
                        .in(someValues);
```

This works fine and gives me the expected results.
Now I need to add another constraint, selecting only entries where in Table C a date-entry (namely 'created') is between a Startdate and Enddate.
How do I chain another predicate to this predicate, or how do I need to modify this predicate, so that I will get the desired effect?

EDIT:

I got an answer to this question here: [JPA 2 criteria API: How to select values from various joined tables without using Metamodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270857/jpa-2-criteria-api-how-to-select-values-from-various-joined-tables-without-usin)

Comment: Perhaps this link should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594309/how-to-rewrite-this-query-using-jpa-criteria-query

Comment: My problem is different from the one in the link presented:
I have many tables that I need to join, but then I have to test against predicates concerning different tables.
If I just chainlink predicates testing if the time of table C is between the correct  values and then check if the value from table D is in the correct values, it will also give me results where the time is correct in table C, but for wrong values in table D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look here, it is the same problem, better described and answered:

[JPA 2 criteria API: How to select values from various joined tables without using Metamodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270857/jpa-2-criteria-api-how-to-select-values-from-various-joined-tables-without-usin)