# JPA 2 criteria API: How to select values from various joined tables without using Metamodel?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following type of query that I wish to convert into a jpa criteria query and the following table structure:

```
Table A 1-->1 Table B  1<--* Table C (proceedings) *-->1 Table D(prcoeedingsstatus)
--------      --------       -------                     -------
 aID           bID           cID                         dID
 ...           ....          timestamp                   textValue
 f_bID         ....          f_bID       
                             f_dID
```

1 A has 1 B, 1 B has many proceedings and each proceeding has a proceedingstatus.

```
SELECT a.*

FROM ((a LEFT JOIN b ON a.f_b = b.id)
        LEFT JOIN proceedings ON b.id = proceedings.f_b)
        RIGHT JOIN proceedingsstatus ON proceedings.f_d = proceedingsstatus.id

WHERE   d.textValue IN ("some unique text")
        AND c.timestamp BETWEEN 'somedate' AND 'anotherdate'
```

When I now try to do something like this for the predicates:

```
Predicate conditions = (root.join("tableB")
                            .joinList("proceedings")
                            .join("proceedingsstatus").get("textValue"))
                            .in(constraintList.getSelectedValues());

Predicate time = cb.between((root.join("tableB")
                            .joinList("proceedings")
                            .<Date>get("timestamp")), dt1.toDate(), dt2.toDate());

constraints = cb.and(conditions, time);
```

Right now it selects entries A where there is at least 1 occurrence of the right proceedingsstatus according to the conditions-predicate if in any of A's proceedings the 'timestamp' matches the time-predicate that I built.
So it would also select an entry A when C.timestamp is correct for a proceeding with the wrong textValue in D, if there is at least one entry C belonging to A with the right textvalue in D.

How can I change it so that it only selects A's where the proceedingsstatus has the right value AND the time of proceeds is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuse the joins instead of creating new ones for each predicate.

```
Join proceedings = root.join("tableB").joinList("proceedings");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, will try it out tomorrow and write if it helps.

Comment: So, tried it out, did exactly what I wanted, thanks very much!